# SSIS Script Task, SqlException Handling Issue

Tags: c#, ssis

What I am trying to do is to create a framework in SSIS to generate tab delimited UTF8 text files dynamically.  The data source is SQL Server, and the queries to be output are stored in a physical database table, from which the SQL query plus a few other parameters (e.g. file output location) are passed to an SSIS script task via variables.  The query is then executed and the results then streamed to the specified location.

This part works fine – however I started having a few issues when I attempted to introduce exception handling.   If there is an error in the source SQL, I would like an exception to be thrown and the SQL Server error message to be inserted back into the source table.  Again, I got this to work, using the SqlException class.  However, depending on the SQL error, a blank 0 byte text file may or may not be generated.  For example, a syntax error in the source SQL will be thrown straight to the catch block, but a divide by 0 error creates a blank 0 byte text file.  In both cases, the source table is updated with the error.  How can I avoid this?  Whatever the error is, I don’t want a file to be generated.

This is what I have cobbled together… I am a noob to C# and this is my first ever stab at C# coding so if there are any glaringly obvious schoolboy errors in here, or if there are ways I can improve this, I would appreciate it if you could point these out!

Thanks

```
/*
   Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
   Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
   The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.
*/

using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace ST_5f2e36fd61064ad8ae13e81d97fe899e.csproj
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        #region VSTA generated code
        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        public void Main()
        {
            //establish connection to data source using ADONET connection manager
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADONET"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


            //variable declarations
            int ReportId = (int)Dts.Variables["ReportId"].Value;
            bool ExportColumnNames =(bool) Dts.Variables["ExportColumnNames"].Value;
            string SQLQuery = Dts.Variables["Query"].Value.ToString();
            string strFilePath = "\\\\" + Path.Combine(Path.Combine(Dts.Variables["OutputServerName"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["OutputFilepath"].Value.ToString()), Dts.Variables["OutputFilename"].Value.ToString());
            string strColumnNames = "";

            SqlDataReader reader;


            using (myADONETConnection)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (reader = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, myADONETConnection).ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        //get the column names from the query into a string variable
                        //or use DataTable instead?  which is better?

                            for (int col = 0; col < reader.FieldCount; col++)
                            {
                                strColumnNames += reader.GetName(col).ToString() + "\t";
                            }
                            // remove final \t from strColumnName string
                            strColumnNames = strColumnNames.Remove(strColumnNames.Length - 1);



                        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(strFilePath)) //creates file; also creates 0 byte file on divide by 0 SQL error...
                        {
                            //insert column names (only if flag on table is set to true)
                            if (ExportColumnNames == true)
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine(strColumnNames);
                            }

                            //insert data
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                //if (reader.HasRows)
                                //{

                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(reader[0].ToString());

                                for (int i = 1; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
                                {
                                    sb.AppendFormat("\t{0}", reader[i]);
                                } //end for
                                writer.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

                                //} //end if

                            } //end while

                        } //end (using streamwriter)

                        //reader.Close();
                    } //end (using reader) (closes the reader)

                    //update source table as success
                    var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblAnalyticsFrameworkControlTable SET ExportDate = GETDATE(), ExportSuccessful = 1 WHERE ID = @ID", myADONETConnection);

                    SqlParameter ID = new SqlParameter();
                    ID.ParameterName = "@ID";
                    ID.Value = ReportId;
                    command.Parameters.Add(ID);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    myADONETConnection.Close();

                } //end try

                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    //insert error message back to table
                    var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblAnalyticsFrameworkControlTable SET ExportDate = GETDATE(), ExportSuccessful = 0, ExportErrorMessage = @ErrorMessage WHERE ID = @ID", myADONETConnection);

                    SqlParameter ErrorMessage = new SqlParameter();
                    ErrorMessage.ParameterName = "@ErrorMessage";
                    ErrorMessage.Value = ex.Message;
                    command.Parameters.Add(ErrorMessage);

                    SqlParameter ID = new SqlParameter();
                    ID.ParameterName = "@ID";
                    ID.Value = ReportId;
                    command.Parameters.Add(ID);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    //remove blank file created by StreamWriter method (preferably without removing pre-existing valid files if possible!)
                    File.Delete(strFilePath);

                } //end catch

                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable data types. When you concatenate them, as you do for `strColumnNames` you are making all these new copies. Use the StringBuilder approach as you do for the body

Comment: Nice job on the commenting for a noob to c#. There are a few recommendations that may help you with your exceptions that you need thown. 1) With your try catch, use a logging system in the catch such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/), easy to setup and you can pass your ex message to that. 2) In addition to your catch (SqlException ex) add another catch that is a generic catch (Exception e). This will find anything that is not a SqlException.  3) In your catch, usually you do not have anything but cleanup code here, dispose/close/etc. 4) Optionally place smaller try catches, costs resources.

Comment: Also, if you just want a generic run query and export to tab delimited file, it's called [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) Use an `Execute Process Task` in SSIS and pass the query in as a parameter

Comment: Thanks guys.  I did consider bcp but unfortunately this does not support code page 65001.

Comment: I still don't understand why a blank text file is being created when a SQL runtime error (e.g. divide / 0) occurs, even though the exception is being handled by SqlException class?